# How to find category-name, page number in http://domain.com/post-type/category/category-name/page/2

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have an URL formatted like so:

`http://domain.com/post-type/category/category-name/page/2`

And need to extract only `category-name` no matter what follows.

For example, in the url:

`http://domain.com/projects/category/print/page/2`

I only want the word

`print`

I am trying this regex: `category\/(.+)\/(?(?=(?:category)\/)^|(.+))\/(.+)\/?$` cobbled together via some searching, but I really am quite confused by Regex.

http://regex101.com/r/uG8pV8

**Note**

I am executing this in PHP (in what I think is regex, correct?). At the moment, the Wordpress code is as so: `$newrules['projects/category/(.*/?)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=project&project_cat=$matches[1]';` which seems to take the entire URL after `projects/category/`

**Edit**

Is it also possible to get the page number as well?

eg: `http://domain.com/post-type/category/category-name/page/2`

Is it possible to get only `category-name` and `2` as separate matches?

Comment: I suppose this is the answer to my edit, after some fiddling: `projects\/category\/(.+?)\/page\/(.+?)$` but for some reason this doesn't work in Wordpress/PHP when I set it to `$rules['projects/category/(.+?)/page/(.+?)$']`

Answer (score 2):

You've to use an ungreedy matcher `.+?` the `?` behind `.+` means **ungready** and it stops matching after finding the first patterm behind itself. In this case this is `/.+`.

```
/category\/(.+?)\/.+/
```

Comment: Ah this works perfectly. Sorry to extend the question, but I seem to now be having an issue with rewrite rules, where my previous rewrite rule was `[projects/category/(.*/?)$] => index.php?post_type=project&project_cat=$matches[1]` - Is there a way to implement this new working regex into this PHP rewrite?

Comment: Please give me specific `from` and `to` URLs to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you - `http://domain.com/projects/category/print/page/2` to `http://domain.com/index.php?post_type=project&project_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]`

Comment: How about this `/category\/(.+)\/page\/(\d+)$/`?

Comment: Hm for some reason it doesn't seem to work, is it due to slash escaping? The current rule is: `projects/category/(.*/?)$`

Comment: What kind of delimiter do u use?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure, is there a way to find out what the delimiter being used is?

Comment: The delimiter is the first and last sign of your regex for `/myregex/` its `/` for `@myregex@` its `@`. If your delimiter is `/` u have to escape the `/` inside your regex with a "\".

Comment: Ok, there doesn't apepar to be a delimiter as the current code is: `projects/category/(.*/?)$` > within: `$rules['projects/category/(.*/?)$']`

Comment: The Regex rule is from Wordpress. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite#Examples

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex.

```
(?<=http:\/\/domain\.com\/projects\/category\/)([^\/]+)
```